# How to minify css styles using webpack 3

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, webpack, frontend

I want to minify/optimize my css for production but for some reason it is showing error with my current implementation. My webpack 3 config.production.js looks like this:

```
var webpack = require("webpack");
var path = require("path");
const ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin");


module.exports = {
    entry: [
        "./src/index.tsx","./src/assets/css/styles.css"
    ],

    output: {
        filename: "bundle.js",
        publicPath: "/",
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist")
    },

    // Enable sourcemaps for debugging webpack's output.
    // devtool: "cheap-module-source-map",

    resolve: {
        // Add '.ts' and '.tsx' as resolvable extensions.
        extensions: [".webpack.js", ".web.js", ".ts", ".tsx", ".js"]
    },

    plugins: [
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
            'process.env': {
                'NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('production')
            }
        }),
        new ExtractTextPlugin("styles.css"),
    ],

    module: {
        rules: [
            // All files with a '.ts' or '.tsx' extension will be handled by 'awesome-typescript-loader'.
            { test: /\.tsx?$/, use: ["awesome-typescript-loader"] },
            // All output '.js' files will have any sourcemaps re-processed by 'source-map-loader'.
            { test: /\.js$/, enforce: "pre", use: "source-map-loader" },
            { test: /\.css$/, use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({ fallback: "style-loader", use: "css-loader" }) }
        ],
        loaders: [ {
            test: /\.js|.jsx?$/,
            exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
            loader: 'babel-loader',
        }, {
            test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg)$/i,
            loaders: [
                'file?hash=sha512&digest=hex&name=[hash].[ext]',
                'image-webpack?bypassOnDebug&optimizationLevel=7&interlaced=false'
            ]
        } ]
    }
};
```

> ERROR in multi ./src/index.tsx ./src/assets/css/styles.css
>   Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'style-loader' in 'C:\Users\iluli\Documents\socfinder_search\frontend'
>    @ multi ./src/index.tsx ./src/assets/css/styles.css
>   npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
>   npm ERR! errno 2
>   npm ERR! socfinder-search@1.0.0 build: `webpack --config webpack.prod.config.js -p`
>   npm ERR! Exit status 2
>   npm ERR!
>   npm ERR! Failed at the socfinder-search@1.0.0 build script.
>   npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

I cannot see my css file into my build folder.

UPDATE: After installing css-loader now styles.css is generated into build, but there is no difference between the build css and dev css. I would want the production to have a minified version of css , for ex all css in one line.

Comment: It seems you are missing [style-loader](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/style-loader) module: `npm install style-loader --save-dev`

Comment: added already  there is no errors now, but also there is no .css file generated into build folder. Seems that it is generating it to ./node_modules/css-loader!./src/assets/css/styles.css

Comment: I already have bundle.js there, do I also need to add bundle.css same as bundle.jss, do u have any example?

Answer (score 1):

Try to add "minimize" options to css-loader:

```
{ test: /\.css$/, use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({ fallback: "style-loader", use: "css-loader", options: { minimize: true} }) }
```

take from [here](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/extract-text-webpack-plugin#url-resolving)

Answer (score 0):

Add the style-loader to the dependency list:

```
npm install style-loader --save-dev
```

Comment: i have already added this, I can see styles.css generated under build folder, but how about if I want it to optimize or minify in one line all css.

Comment: That would be another question on stackoverflow.

Comment: i am limited to making questions on stackoverflow within a period of 2h, do u mind sharing a link or giving an example on how to minify the css using webpack, also if this was not doing the minifying I am wondering what did I do using this ExtractTextPlugin ?

Comment: in fact my question is how about minifying the css using webpack, so I guess you can answer here already!